# Information Management Policy Settings using CSOM in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Is it possible to set the Information Management Policy Settings for content types in a document library using CSOM in SPO...???

I am trying to set the label for the document content type in a document library.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not supported with CSOM to get/set Information Management policy.

here is link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/302be20f-025f-4409-a8a2-83f946b17060/information-management-policy-settings-using-csom-in-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointdevelopment

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cb6b38c9-b34c-4a5c-86f6-7edb5746f7eb/barcode-policy-class-for-csom-?forum=sharepointdevelopment